# How deep down is the jungle temple?

Tags: terraria

I'm looking for the jungle temple in Terraria, but, I've not had much luck yet.

I figured I'd make a lot of Hellevators, and I'd soon bump into it, but, I'm not sure how deep down it is.

Does anyone know how deep down it is located, and is there a better method for finding it?

Comment: I imagine it is randomly generated in the jungle.

Comment: Its pretty big, you might have better luck just exploring the natural jungle caves.

Comment: @ColinD Quite possibly, as the answer might end up being the same.

Comment: @RedSheep Have you defeated Plantera yet?

Comment: Yeah, defeated Plantera, not before dying countless times! :D